# Trying to understand AWS lambda limits while attached as a target group to an application load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-limits

I am trying to understand how application load balancer on AWS works while paired with lambda functions. If I attach a lambda as a target group to an alb, would I be able to invoke that lambda function beyond the normal lambda function concurrency limits that are set in each account through for example requesting the load balancer's domain url which is listed as the "DNS name" in AWS console, or an alias record associated with the alb, etc. Any knowledge would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I attach a lambda as a target group to an alb, would I be able to invoke that lambda function beyond the normal lambda function concurrency limits

No. lambda limits are independent of the way you execute it. So the fact that you use ALB, does not matter.

You can always ask AWS service to increase lambda concurrency limit.